# display warning when method is called?

Tags: ruby

I have a gem that discourages use of `stylesheet_link_tag` - I'd like to display a warning in console every time `stylesheet_link_tag` gets called, without  reopening or copying the logic of this method (my concern is different versions of rails will have different implementations).

Is there a way in ruby to hook into an existing method (**without reopening it**), or perhaps a way I can detect that a method of that name was called so I can then proceed to display my custom warning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Super** won't work. There is no superclass for a module. You need an `alias`

Put this somewhere in `application_helper.rb`, before all definitions:

```
  module ::ActionView::Helpers::AssetTagHelper
    alias stylesheet_link_tag_original stylesheet_link_tag
    def stylesheet_link_tag(*params)
      logger.warn 'Stylesheet link tag called!'
      stylesheet_link_tag_original(*params)
    end
  end
```

Comment: @lfender6445, is there any reason for Rails `alias_method`? Pure Ruby `alias` seems to do the 100% same job in this case.

Comment: you know its funny, at first i didnt think it was valid syntax because alias isn't called with a comma. i added the comma and my editor started complaining! as it turns out this is completely intentional i am going to update the answer

Comment: @lfender6445, and it also does not need `:`. `alias` is a plain Ruby keyword that takes two method names. I checked the code before submitting the answer.

Comment: A mixin gets included as the superclass of the class and the original superclass becomes the superclass of the mixin class, therefore `super` works just fine. Provided, of course, that the superclass has a corresponding method. With `prepend`, the mixin gets prepended to the ancestry chain as if it were a subclass, so `super` refers to the class doing the prepending.

Comment: @JörgWMittag `AssetTagHelper` is not a `class`. The `super` doesn't work. It seeks for the method in the super class of a view. Tested and confirmed several times: `super: no superclass method `stylesheet_link_tag' for #<#<Class:0x000000056d1f00>:0x000000056d0e70>`